# It is given that $\frac{x^2}{2}=xy-\ln(1+xy)$.How can we write $y=f(x)?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

It is given that $\frac{x^2}{2}=xy-\ln(1+xy)$.How can we write $y=f(x)?$

My try:$$\frac{x^2}{2}=xy-\ln(1+xy)$$
$$\implies\ln(1+xy)=xy-\frac{x^2}{2}$$
$$\implies(1+xy)=e^{(xy-\frac{x^2}{2})}$$
$$\implies e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(1+xy)=e^{xy}$$
$$\implies e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+xy\,e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}=e^{xy}$$

After that I am clueless.Thank you.

Comment: Without the lambert W function, I doubt that you can. Why do you want to do so?

Comment: can you do this by using Lambert W function?

Answer (score 3):

Not all implicit equations, which is what you have, can be written as an elementary function of one of the variables (or a function at all, for that matter).

In this case, you have likely noted that taking the exp of both sides "liberates" one copy of y, and "captures" the other; taking the inverse simply undoes your operation. There is not a simple way to get them both "free." I'll echo the commenter here and mention that the [Lambert W-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) can help with the solution to equations that involve polynomials and exponentials, but it's worth noting that the Lambert W-Function isn't even quite a "function" since it is multi-valued.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equation$$\frac{x^2}{2}=xy-\ln(1+xy)$$ and define $z=1+xy$ to get $$\frac{x^2}{2}=z-1-\ln(z)$$ Using the classical manipulations given in [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), you should end with $$z=-W\left(-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-1}\right)$$ from which $$y=-\frac{1+W\left(-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-1}\right)}{x}$$

Answer (score 2):

I will solve:

$$f(x)=u-\ln (1+u)$$

For $u$. Firstly, adding one and exponentiating both sides gives:

$$e^{f(x)+1}=\frac{e^{1+u}}{1+u}$$

This means that,

$$e^{f(x)+1}(1+u)=e^{1+u}$$

So,

$$(1+u)e^{-(1+u)}e^{f(x)+1}=1$$

$$-(1+u)e^{-(1+u)}e^{f(x)+1}=-1$$

And,

$$-(1+u)e^{-(1+u)}=-e^{-(f(x)+1)}$$

So,

$$-(1+u)=W(-e^{-(f(x)+1)})$$

$$u=-W(-e^{-(f(x)+1)})-1$$

---

If $u=xy$ then we have,

$$y=\frac{-W(-e^{-(f(x)+1)})-1}{x}$$